# android calculate rise over run from angle

Tags: android, math, game-physics

We are trying to calculate the rise over the run of an object. We know the angle of a right triangle and we know the run. When we use the scientific Microsoft calculator we get the tangent of the angle and multiply by the run to get the rise. 
`angle = 7.5` `tangent = 0.1316` in degrees multiply by run and ans 1.579 From this we now know how to set the X and Y coordinates of the `Imageview` object 
We have seen all types of answers about how to do this with Java for Android none of which give the results based on the use of the MS calculator. We tried this

```
float T = (float) toRadians(tan(7.5));
```

Not even close we also tried toDegrees 
So the we have two questions

1. How to calculate the rise knowing the run and the angle?
2. Is there a better way to set the X and Y value of the object so it will follow a path on a desired angle?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark We see our mistake now the SO post we copied from took us down the wrong road for formatting but the concept was ok      //7.5 is the angle
                float T = (float) Math.tan(toRadians(7.5));
                float rise = T * 12;// and 12 is the RUN
                System.out.println("*************** RISE  "+rise);

Answer (score 0):

tan(angle) = rise/run. what you need is to rearrange this.
rise = tan(angle) * run

Comment: Yes. Thanks, I need more coffee.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP this is accomplished like this:

`$rise = tan(deg2rad($degrees)) * $distance;`

It took me a while to figure out that PHP's tan() function expects the angle to be in radians, so I had to convert to that first.

I know that's not an Android-specific response, but I'm leaving it here anyway in case it saves someone else some time.